# Testing pull-request on other person's package

Tags: python, github, fork, pull-request

I opened an [issue](https://github.com/mvantellingen/python-zeep/issues/177) in a package that I need for my job, and now the author is asking me to test a [pull request](https://github.com/mvantellingen/python-zeep/pull/205). The problem is... I don't really know what is the preferred way to do that.

The only way I see now is that I fork the repository, download and apply the pull request as a patch and then import the function from that project... surely there must be a better way? I'm using PyCharm on Ubuntu.

Comment: Just clone the mentioned branch: https://github.com/mvantellingen/python-zeep/tree/multiple-msg-parts

Comment: Oh my, I didn't notice that it's possible... should I delete this question?

Comment: I don't think that's needed; I've written the answer below to be applicable not just to your situation but to the general issue of getting a local copy of a pull request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GitHub pull request names the source:

> mvantellingen wants to merge 12 commits into `master` from `multiple-msg-parts`

`multiple-msg-parts` is just another branch in the same repository. Just clone that repository and check out [that specific branch](https://github.com/mvantellingen/python-zeep/tree/multiple-msg-parts).

Other pull requests may have been created from a branch in a different repository; the source repository will then have a `<username>:<branch>` form, at which point you'd clone the project from that specific user to get that branch. For example, [this pull request](https://github.com/mvantellingen/python-zeep/pull/185) is sourced from `andrewserong:check-node-get-children`, so you'd clone [`andrewserong/python-zeep`](https://github.com/andrewserong/python-zeep) and switch to the `check-node-get-children` branch instead.

PyCharm lets you [clone directly from GitHub](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.2/cloning-a-repository-from-github.html); once cloned use the *VCS* menu item to switch branches.

Answer (score 1):

> The only way I see now is that I fork the repository, download and apply the pull request as a patch [...]

As [Martijn Pieters commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39861662/testing-pull-request-on-other-persons-package#comment67011346_39861662): clone the repository and check out the mentioned branch. You can do that without forking it on GitHub and without manually applying the pull request:

```
git clone git@github.com:mvantellingen/python-zeep.git
git checkout multiple-msg-parts
```

or even in a single command:

```
git clone git@github.com:mvantellingen/python-zeep.git --branch multiple-msg-parts
```

> [...] and then import the function from that project

I guess you won't get around that part if you want to test the pull request's change.

Though, the author didn't ask you *to test* the pull request (even though they might have meant to do so); they asked you *whether* you *can* test it:

> I'm working on a fix in #205. It required some refactoring, are you able to give it a try for me?

To which "No, because I don't know how." would have been an acceptable answer. ;-)

Comment: I like the sense of humor in this one ;)